Danger-swift-xcodesummary in XcodeCloud
I'm currently implementing a CI in Xcode Cloud and I'd like to use the Danger-Swift plugin Xcodesummary (here)
The issue is that I get through my env variable the path to the .xcresult file that contains all the information I need but Xcodesummary wants a specifically formatted json which I don't know how to generate.
FYI: I already tried to use this:
xcrun xcresulttool get --legacy (optional in the CI, mandatory locally) --format json --path test.xcresult > build-report.json

and what this does is generate a json out of the xcresult, indeed, but absolutely not in the right format.
I'm losing my mind here, please help.
